# Short-form goroutine return values

Tags: go

I have been using Go for a while. I wonder is there any short-form code to get the return values from goroutine.

```golang
    x := 3
    ch := make(chan int)
    go func(xIn int) (xOut int) {
        xOut = x + 1
        ch <- xOut
        return xOut
    }(x)
    nextX := <-ch
    fmt.Println(x, nextX)
```

Suggested short-form:

```golang
    x := 3
    nextX := go func(xIn int) (xOut int) {
        xOut = x + 1
        return xOut
    }(x)
    fmt.Println(x, nextX)
```

**The emphasis:**

The question is not about is not about how to do it but why go-complier did not provide such feature.

Comment: No, for the simple reason that there never is any return value from a goroutine. Goroutines aren't functions.

Answer (score 3):

Let us posit the existence of some function `f()` with some return type `T`.

You wish to capture the returned value of `f()`.  Obviously, we can do this with:

```
x := f()
```

If:

```
x := go f()
```

waited for `f()` to `return` some value to assign to `x`, what would be the difference between these two calls?

(If:

```
x := go f()
```

does not wait for `f()` to `return` a value, what should happen when you try to access variable `x`?)

---

If you wish to write:

```
x := 3
nextX := func(xIn int) (xOut int) {
    xOut = x + 1
    return xOut
}(x)
fmt.Println(x, nextX)
```

you may do so in Go as it exists today.  (Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XHkVEB4J3kY).  Also, I suspected you wanted the inner function to use its `xIn` variable, rather than the closure-captured `x` variable, but the effect is the same either way.)